# what is ".cat" in ".cat.categories"?

Tags: pandas, categories

I am not sure what `.cat` is and why we need it while `.categories` itself is already asking the interpreter to list the category of choice ?
For example, why should I use this:

```
housing_df.REMODEL.cat.categories
```

And not this:

```
housing_df.REMODEL.categories
```

Pandas documentation explains "String.cat.categories" but I do not understand that.

Comment: It's not String.cat.catetories. It's [Series.cat.categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.categories.html). While you don't understand the docs, try other sources such as [this](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-series-unique-vs-series-cat-categories/).

Comment: Thanks. But my question was: ".cat" is just how python works? I expected to see ".categories" only. The link you sent only says how to use it.

Comment: Why did you expect to see `.categories` only? Why is this an issue to have `cat`? This is just a design choice, there is not much to comment here.

Comment: Well, then you don`t know what a specific statement is for and keep memorizing things.

Comment: If you look at the overview documentation for Series https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html you see the Series.cat methods - "Categorical-dtype specific methods and attributes are available under the Series.cat accessor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.cat` is called an accessor object. It allows you to access attributes and methods that are specific to categorical columns. There are similar accessors in pandas: `.dt` for date-time, `.str` for string, `.plot` for plotting and so on. This is a design decision made by pandas developers. In general, these are used for namespacing so that attributes and methods are better organized and they don't cause name collision.